# TRING_TOO_LONG=Name: data value too large: campaign_name (max length=80)

Tags: campaign

i was trying to create a new campaign through api with the name having characters more than 80. i was ended with below error

> TRING_TOO_LONG=Name: data value too large: [campaign_name] (max length=80).

is there anyway to increase the max-length more than 80 character in my SF account? or how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a campaign with the name exceeding 80 characters as per the Salesforce standards.

## [What is the maximum length of system “Name” fields?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003589&type=1)

> - "Account Name" field is 255
> - "Contact First Name" field is 40
> - "Contact Last Name" field is 80
> - "Opportunity Name" field is 120
> - "Lead First Name" field is 40
> - "Lead Last Name" field is 80
> - "Campaign Name" field is 80
> - "Contract Name" field is 80
> - "Solution Name/ Solution Title" is 255
> - "Price Book Name" is 255
> - "Macro Name" field is 255
> - Custom Object Name field is 80

Comment: In the future, please include the relevant text from a linked resource. Links sometimes go bad, which can make the answer useless. I've fixed this answer for you. Please read [answer] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method to split long name and create campaign

```
String str = 'kjsbjkcbjkadbscjkbjkabscbabcbsakbcjkbsabclkbaskjcbkcsvdgcjsvdcjhsdvchjsdhvchjsdvhjcsdjcbajcascascajnckjnjjkBCKJbkjckjnzkjckjdskjcbkbdskc';
    str= str.substring(0,80);
    campaign  camp=new campaign ();
    camp.name=str;
    insert camp;
```